# A function to fetch blog content via rss feed

Tags: rss, blog, automatic-updates, feed

I am trying to make a function which take an rss fedd URL and fetches the most recent 2 posts. I have tried to remake the snippet from here to a full function in funtions.php as following. I don't want to use a plugin for this since the plugins I have looked at have been close to impossible to style with my own html...

```
function fetch_feed_from_blogg($path) {
$rss = fetch_feed($path);

if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : 

$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(2); 
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
endif;

function get_first_image_url($html)
{
  if (preg_match('/<img.+?src="(.+?)"/', $html, $matches)) {
  return $matches[1];
  }
}

function shorten($string, $length) 
{
$suffix = '&hellip;';

$short_desc = trim(str_replace(array("/r", "/n", "/t"), ' ', strip_tags($string)));
    $desc = trim(substr($short_desc, 0, $length));
    $lastchar = substr($desc, -1, 1);
      if ($lastchar == '.' || $lastchar == '!' || $lastchar == '?') $suffix='';
          $desc .= $suffix;
    return $desc;
}

if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
else 
foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :

$html = '<ul class="rss-items" id="wow-feed"> <li class="item"> <span class="rss-image"><img src="' .get_first_image_url($item->get_content()). '"/></span>
    <span class="data"><h5><a href="' . esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ) . '" title="' . esc_html( $item->get_title() ) . '"' . esc_html( $item->get_title() ) . '</a></h5></li></ul>';

 return $html;
}
```

I am also trying to make it so that it can be used several times on a single page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, avoid defining functions inside functions. PHP doesn't have a problem with it, but it's usually a sign you're "doing it wrong" and it just leads to unnecessary headaches.

Second, your `foreach` loop at the bottom is a little malformed. You need to define the `<ul>` outside the loop, and then *append* to `$html` - otherwise you just end up with the last item!

```
function wpse_187819_get_feed_html( $url ) {
    if ( is_wp_error( $rss = fetch_feed( $url ) ) )
        return; // Bail

    $maxitems  = $rss->get_item_quantity( 2 );
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

    $html = '<ul class="rss-items" id="wow-feed">';

    if ( $maxitems ) {
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) {
            $title = esc_attr( $item->get_title() );
            $link  = esc_url( $item->get_permalink() );

            $html .= '<li class="item">'; 
                if ( preg_match( '/<img.+?src="(.+?)"/', $item->get_content(), $matches ) )
                    $html .= '<span class="rss-image"><img src="' . $matches[1] . '"/></span>';

                $html .= '<span class="data"><h5><a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '"' . $title . '</a></h5></span>';
            $html .= '</li>';
        }

    } else {
        $html .= '<li>No items</li>';
    }

    // All done, now close the <ul>
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: "First things first, avoid defining functions inside functions." -- Note to @HannesH: As stated, PHP lets you do this and doesn't complain but the function is not really "nested". That is, it is still defined in global scope and not limited to the parent "container" function, but isn't available until after the parent function runs. Confusing, misleading, and weird? Kinda :) See: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: Thank you, it worked great and thanks for you being kind when helping me!